# Role creation in drupal at multi level?

Tags: users

I want to create to some role as business manager,manager and last is handler.
Business manager should have the role who can create manager user .
Manager role should have the privilege who can create the handler user.

Comment: Notice that describing what you want to achieve is not asking a question, without any explicit question. You need to show what you tried, what problems you found, etc. The question in the title doesn't count as asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Check once [subuser](https://www.drupal.org/project/subuser) or [subs_roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/subs_roles). May be helpful in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for giving me support. subuser module is asking for Relation is missing when i am going to enable module...How can I get i relation.

Comment: Relation is the dependent module , so you have to enable https://www.drupal.org/project/relation and https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools
 also